# Sharing a network port between two docker containers

Tags: networking, docker

I am running a binary-protocol TCP server in a container.  In order to facilitate zero downtime upgrades, I have constructed a flow where an instance can forward its server socket to the server in the new container by way of a unix domain socket.  This works like a charm until the moment where the first container shuts down.  Since it is the container which has published the port, the port de-publishes once the container closes.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this case.

Here's the basic rundown of what I'm doing:

```
# start the first container, starts listening on 3290
docker run -p 3290:3290 --name first /my/server/app

# start the second container, "steals" the server socket on 3290 from first
docker run --net container:first /my/server/app

# the second container, at this point, is handling connections from 3290
# when the first container is killed below, the port is de-published
# and the second container stops receiving connections
docker rm first
```

At first, I thought that a user-defined network would work best, but I cannot find a way to publish a port on a user-defined network.  Another option I am considering is to construct another container which handles the publishing of ports, then have all other containers borrow the network from that running container.  I think that approach will work, I just don't like the idea of having to have this extra container lying around for no other purpose.  Though perhaps that is the only solution, thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried to use a proxy such as HAPROXY. If you are using DockerCloud you can just use a service endpoint, to reduce the risk even further.Then use the HAPROXY to point to the individual services. This would mean you can have zero downtime.

Comment: I've considered using HAPROXY, but I'm hesitant for a few reasons.  

When I examined the configuration pages for HAPROXY, it feels like it's tailored towards HTTP services.  My service a raw binary TCP server, so I don't know that it fits with the proxy approach very well.  Though I may be missing something.

Comment: It can be used for multiple services, its main use is HTTP, but it can handle any TCP connection. For our uses we have it handling HTTP traffic, and other data as well.

Comment: Does it maintain the source information for the TCP connection, and can you ingest the network/port information for the individual containers?  Note that I am engaging with docker directly on a machine.  I am not using an intermediary service like DockerCloud.

Comment: It does maintain source information for the TCP connection, it also adds some headers.

Are you meaning Stickiness to the individual container? or something else?

Comment: How can it add headers to a TCP connection?  I think you're talking about an HTTP connection.

Comment: Sorry, yeah it adds headers to HTTP connections, but that wouldn't be relavant to you.
Have a look at https://www.linickx.com/load-balance-anything-with-haproxy

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/:

> Load balancing: You can expose the ports for services to an external load balancer. Internally, the swarm lets you specify how to distribute service containers between nodes.

Video at the bottom of this post maybe interesting for you: https://blog.docker.com/2016/06/docker-1-12-built-in-orchestration/.

Comment: I'm only running this on one node though.

Comment: IPVS works with single node: https://blog.codeship.com/kernel-load-balancing-for-docker-containers-using-ipvs/